# How to generate executable jar for SpringBoot application with Spring Boot Loader

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, executable-jar

How we can generate executable jar for SpringBoot application in below structure

```
example.jar
 |
 +-META-INF
 |  +-maven
 |  +-MANIFEST.MF
 +-org
 |  +-springframework
 |     +-boot
 |        +-loader
 |           +-<spring boot loader classes>
 +-BOOT-INF
    +-classes
    |  +-com
    |     +-mycompany
    |        +-project
    |           +-YourClasses.class
    +-lib
    |  +-dependency1.jar
    |  +-dependency2.jar
```

### Pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <commons-lang3.version>3.9</commons-lang3.version>
       <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>4.3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                        <output>${basedir}</output>
                        <withXml>false</withXml>
                        <configOptions>
                            <library>spring-mvc</library>
                            <sourceFolder>src/main/java</sourceFolder>
                            <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                            <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                            <generateModelsTests>false</generateModelsTests>
                            <generateModelsDocumentation>false</generateModelsDocumentation>
                            <java8>true</java8>
                            <serializableModel>false</serializableModel>
                            <async>false</async>
                            <dateLibrary>java8-localdatetime</dateLibrary>
                            <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                            <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
                            <useOptional>true</useOptional>
                            <hideGenerationTimestamp>true</hideGenerationTimestamp>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>org/**/*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${dockerfile-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>push</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <repository>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</repository>
                    <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                    <buildArgs>
                        <JAR_FILE>${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
                    </buildArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <name>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</name>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>        
        
</project>
```

Above is the `pom.xml` of my application which is configured to generate the jar file.
Currently, when I do mvn clean package the jar is getting generated but not the executable one.

Expectation:
Dependencies should be placed in a nested BOOT-INF/lib directory.

Comment: You are generating a war not a jar file. Please add your pom.xml.

Comment: Sorry! it is typo error. It is jar file I have to generate.

Comment: Add pom.xml and corrected the description . Please check

Comment: THere isn't anything obivously wrong (at least it looks like that). One thing is why the compiler plugin, instead of using the one from the parent (do you need the exclude?). One thing, dependency-wise, is that you should use `spring-boot-starter-validation` instead of `validation-api` as a dependency. One thing is that you obfuscated the dependencies and indicates that there are actual dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.It is generating the Jar file but not in the structure as I mentioned above.